# How to prompt if the user is exist in database

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php 
    include('dbcon.php');
    $code = $_POST['code']; 
    $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,"INSERT into attendance(firstname,lastname,type,year_level,date_added)Select firstname,lastname,type,year_level,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM member WHERE code='$code'") or die("Error ".mysqli_error());
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {  
        if(!$result) {
            echo "Database NOT Found.";
        } else {
            $result;
            header('location:add_member_attendance.php');
        }
    } else {           
    }  
?>
```

I want to display prompt if it successfully entered the data and if the user is not found in database but I don't know what problem of my code. Thanks for helping me

Comment: problem ? where? got any error ? got something that doesn't work ?

Comment: @t-n-y No error but I want to prompt/display that the user is successfully entered or the user is doesn't exist in database

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query("INSERT into attendance(firstname,lastname,type,year_level,date_added)Select firstname,lastname,type,year_level,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM member WHERE code='$code'");
$result = ($dbcon,$query);

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if ($num_rows > 0) {

  // do something
}
else {
die("Error ".mysqli_error($dbcon));
  // do something else
}

}
```

Comment: it's recording but the error is there "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\sti_lms\attendance_save.php on line 22" and "Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp64\www\sti_lms\attendance_save.php on line 30" error .

Comment: sorry It didn't work there's a error in "$result = ($dbcon,$query); so I change it into $result=($query); and I insert the dbcon inside the query, but after that same error thanks for the response my friend

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
<?php 
include('dbcon.php');
$code = $_POST['code']; 


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{  
$insert=mysqli_query($dbcon,"Select firstname,lastname,type,year_level,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM member WHERE code='$code'") or die("There was an error checking due to".mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($insert)>0){
// this means that the code already exist;
$result="INSERT into attendance(firstname,lastname,type,year_level,date_added)Select firstname,lastname,type,year_level,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM member WHERE code='$code'";

//check if the query run
if(mysqli_query($dbcon,$result)){//or you can do mysql_query($result)
header('location:add_member_attendance.php');
//you can do anything you want here 
}else{
echo "The insert query did not run due to ".mysql_error();
}
}else{

echo "The code doesnt exist"
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I put the user that exist or not in database  but It says " The code doesn't exist " thanks for response my friend